# Timeout occuring when sending business object through WCF Callback

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, callback

I have a WCF service implemented with a call back contract that I am trying to send a business object through. I have the business object decorated with DataContract() and DataMember() attributes, and it contains the following number of properties:

- ints: 3
- strings: 4
- XElement: 1
- other objects: 5 (also decorated with DataContract() and DataMember()

Whenever I try and send this object over the callback, the service times-out. I have tried creating other objects with fewer properties to send through the callback, and can get it to go through if there is only one property, but if I have any more than one property, the service times out.

Is there something wrong in my configuration? I have tried the default wsDualHttpBinding, as well as a customBinding (as displayed below) and I have tried all sorts of different settings with the maxBufferSize, maxBufferPoolSize, and maxReceivedMessageSize. I don't want to increase the timeout, as I would like this object to arrive to my client fairly quickly. Please somebody help me...if I had any hair left I would have pulled it out by now!!!!!

I have configured my service as such:

Server Configuration:

```
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="DualBindingConfig">
            <reliableSession flowControlEnabled="true" maxPendingChannels="128" />
            <compositeDuplex />
            <oneWay/>
            <binaryMessageEncoding/>
            <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="655360000" maxBufferPoolSize="655360000" />
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="Agent_Utility_WCF.Callback.AgentMessagingBehavior"
            name="Agent_Utility_WCF.Callback.AgentMessaging">
            <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="DualBindingConfig" bindingName="AgentMessaging" contract="Agent_Utility_WCF.Callback.IAgentMessaging">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Agent_Utility_WCF.Callback.AgentMessagingBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="160" maxConcurrentSessions="100"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Client Configuration:

```
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="AgentMessaging_IAgentMessaging">
            <reliableSession acknowledgementInterval="00:00:00.2000000" flowControlEnabled="true"
                inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" maxPendingChannels="4" maxRetryCount="8"
                maxTransferWindowSize="8" ordered="true" reliableMessagingVersion="Default" />
            <compositeDuplex />
            <oneWay maxAcceptedChannels="10" packetRoutable="false">
                <channelPoolSettings idleTimeout="00:02:00" leaseTimeout="00:10:00"
                    maxOutboundChannelsPerEndpoint="10" />
            </oneWay>
            <binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                maxSessionSize="2048">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            </binaryMessageEncoding>
            <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:666/Callback/AgentMessaging.svc"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="AgentMessaging_IAgentMessaging"
        contract="AgentMessaging.IAgentMessaging" name="AgentMessaging_IAgentMessaging">
        <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
    </endpoint>
</client>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your web.config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
        <listeners>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="sdt"
                     type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                     initializeData= "WcfDetailTrace.svclog" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Then invoke your web service method. This will generate *WcfDetailTrace.svclog* in the root of your web site. Open this file with [SvcTraceViewer.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx). This should give you pretty much information on what's going on.

Comment: Doing this yielded these results:

There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:submittedJob. The InnerException message was 'Type 'Utility.DAO.SubmittedJob' with data contract name 'SubmittedJob:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Utility.DAO' is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Comment: You could use the KnownTypeAttribute (http://whiletrue.nl/blog/?p=36) in order to list all classes deriving from your base class.

Comment: I think I found the issue...in the webservice I had defined the method as accepting an object type, and was trying to send in a type of SubmittedJob. I changed the webservice to accept SubmittedJob, and the timeout error went away.

Answer (score 0):

How big are the other objects? For example, how large is the `XElement`'s subtree? The graph for an object can get quite large eventually, in particular if it calls into other objects.

A simple investigative approach might be to remove the `[DataMember]` attributes except perhaps one of the strings, and re-introduce them one at a time until it breaks.

Comment: I created another test object with only one property with this goal in mind and successfully submitted it through my webservice. I added another property after that and it would no longer go through...

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/retrieving-huge-amount-of-data-from-wcf-service-in-silverlight-application/.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have abandoned the silverlight project for now.

Comment: I almost had to abandon one as well, until I found this ... maybe next time!